# Tomcat apps are not available from another computers when Tomcat is started as windows service

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I installed tomcat to win2003 server. When I start it by **tomcat/bin/startup.bat**, I can open my application in browser on the same computer with URL http://localhost:8080/app and from other computer in our LAN with URL http://SERVER_IP:8080/app
But when I start tomcat as a windows service (installed by **service.bat install service_name** from tomcat/bin directory), my app is not available from other computers, only from the same computer by http://localhost:8080/app.

What should I do to solve this ?

Comment: It is a windows firewall issue. Try this, [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209618/tomee-service-will-not-allow-to-access-the-application-from-another-lan-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that may be your server's firewall is blocking the request.

Configure firewall to open port no. 8080

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the attribute `address="ip.adress"` to the `connector` element in your `server.xml` configuration file.

On the other hand the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) says: "For servers with more than one IP address, this attribute specifies which address will be used for listening on the specified port. By default, this port will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server."

Please check also whether a firwall prevents access from remote machines