# TomEE Service will not allow to access the application from another LAN Machine

Tags: windows, tomcat, service

I have deployed my webapps in apache-tomee-plus-1.5.1 and start the server using startup.bat in a windows VM. It's working fine and accessible from any other LAN machine using VM's ip, i.e., 192.168.1.236:8080/archiva.

Now, I want to install the server as a service. For that I have install a service using "service.bat install Archiva" command. When I start the service the application is working fine using localhost/192.168.1.236 from the VM. But not accessible from other LAN machine. 
FYI, when I start the service the tomcat home page is shown after hitting 192.168.1.236:8080.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Windows Start --> Control Panel
2. Open Windows Firewall(If not showing, please search it and open).
3. Click on Allow a Program or Feature through windows firewall
   [see image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVzJC.png)
4. Click on Change settings and then Allow another program...
5. Then add all the TomEE.*.exe and press ok.
   [see image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9TrX.png)
6. Restart your service and application is available from LAN.